# How to get column in 2-D array in java by Foreach loop?

Tags: java, arrays, foreach

I can get a row from a 2D array in java by foreach loop like :

```
        int[][] array = new int[5][5] 
        for (int[] row : array) {
        for (int c : row) {
        }
        }
```

But How can I get the column form 2D array by foreach loop ? Or is this possible to get column from 2D array by foreach loop ?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you clarify the question? Do you want the index of the column, using foreach means you dont get an index. If you want the index use a traditional for loop.

Comment: Are you sure that your array is a perfect square matrix (N x N) of same length and width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible. You'll have to use the traditional for loop :

```
int[][] array = new int[5][5] 
for (int j = 0; j < array[0].length; j++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        int current = array[i][j];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

One alternative can be

```
    int i =0;
    for (int k : array[0]){
        for (int[] row : array) {
            System.out.println(row[i]);
        }
        i++;
    }
```

Comment: This is a clever one. :D

Answer (score 0):

2D array is just a conceptual meaning. in fact 2d array is a combination of multiple one-dimensional array. Therefore you cannot access the columns without using a counter. even if you use for each loop you need a counter inside.

If you need to get all the columns then you can make a loop with number of column. But in this case all the rows should have the same number of columns (elements)

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int [][] yourArray = {{1,2,3,4,5,6},//sample 2d array with 6 rows and six columns
                    {1,2,3,4,5,6},      //this is actually a collection of 6 different 1d arrays
                    {1,2,3,4,5,6},
                    {1,2,3,4,5,6},
                    {1,2,3,4,5,6},
                    {1,2,3,4,5,6}};

    int yourColumn = 3; //example of selected column (be careful columns start from 0)

    for(int[] row: yourArray)
    {
        System.out.println(row[yourColumn]);
    }

}
```